# Sharing a dictionary of Queues between Processes?

Tags: python, websocket, architecture, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a problem which goes as follows:

I have a Websocket API (Flask SocketIO), which has only one endpoint. The endpoint returns a list of results, but they are not returned/`emitted` in one go. Instead they are yielded to the client one by one as soon as they are ready, just like a Python generator.

These results are produced by X individual workers, each in a Python `Process`. These workers workers work in serial, not in parallel, meaning that they each produce different results, all of which are to be sent over the API to the client. When an API request hits, the client should be served with such-and-such many results, from each of the X workers.

The workers are thus not redundant; the results from each of them should be served to the client. Let's say for example that one worker produces 2 pictures, another worker produces 5 different historical texts; whatever.

The workers work at different speeds. If an API request comes in, one of the workers will finish very soon, but the slowest one will finish much later. Obviously, I want the fast worker to be ready to produce results for the next API client, so that he can get some results faster.

How to achieve this goal?

I attempted to do as follows: Have a dictionary of queues that is shared between the workers. When an API request comes in, create a new entry in the dictionary, keyed with a request ID, and valued with a new Queue. A websocket API can then `yield` from the reqeust-ID-specific Queue, as soon as the results are ready.

But the attempt is not feasible, because a dictionary cannot be shared across processes. If you create a new Queue, keyed on the specific request ID, in one process, the other ones will not see the queue.

Comment: You said, "a dictionary cannot be shared across processes." But that is not true of one created by a `multiprocessing.SyncManager` instance as in:  `import multiprocessing; manager = multiprocessor.Manager(); d = manager.dict()`

Comment: @Booboo. Yes. but can you add `manegeer.Queue()`s to it? As far as I can understand, no.

Comment: Just a suggestion: There may be an alternate solution you haven't thought of. Maybe it's me, but I don't find there are enough details to fully follow what you are describing. Perhaps if you were to provide some code or pseudo-code so we could see how the queues get created and destroyed, processes are created (using a pool?) and the workers write to them and results get sent back (do you really mean `yield`?). You can even assume that you could do what you want with dictionaries and queues. Then the details would become clearer and you might get more assistance, if not necessarily from me.